# ACTION_SENDTO intent not working in Navigation Drawer Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-intent

So I'm making this app, and it contains several fragments linked to a main activity using a Navigation drawer. One of the fragments' XML layouts contains a button that, when clicked, will send an email. I'm testing this on the emulator. It has worked on another app, but not this. Here's the code:

```
public class AboutPage extends Fragment {
    public AboutPage() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_page, container, false);
        Button contactButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_button);
        contactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:email@gmail.com"));
                intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Primus Suggestion or Issue");
                intent.setType("plain/text");
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email using:"));
                } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You don't have any email apps to contact us.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

It keeps on displaying the toast, yet it works on the other app where the intent is created in the Main Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope below will works for you:-**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"lumberjackapps@gmail.com"});
  intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Primus Suggestion or Issue");
  intent.setType("text/plain");
  if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
  getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email using:"));
  }
  else {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You don't have any email apps to contact us.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: It works, and thank you for that, but do you know why my original code didn't work?

Comment: check difference between `ACTION_SEND` & `ACTIN_SENDTO` from this  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO)

"intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null" is always null for ACTION_SENDTO, thatswhy your code is not working.